# Get sessionscoped cdi from requestscoped

Tags: java, cdi, inject

I want to inject a SessionScoped object which its already in session in another RequestBean, and its injecting it successfully but it seems its creating a new instance of the class instead of bringing me what its in the session at the moment.

My problem its something related with:
[Get access to session scoped CDI bean from request scoped CDI Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512206/get-access-to-session-scoped-cdi-bean-from-request-scoped-cdi-bean)

but at the end it was post no solution to it.

Comment: CDI will (for `@NormalScope`) inject _client proxy_ objects and not the referenced bean instance. Is this what you're seeing?

Comment: yeah, i am getting not a referenced bean object with the current values that where modified in the session, but a new instance of this one

Comment: The proxies should dynamically invoke the session objects though for all methods.

Comment: Post code and make sure you include the imports