# Get access to CDI bean from another CDI bean

Tags: jsf, scope, cdi, inject

I have to get access to a session scoped CDI bean from another request scoped CDI bean. I have got:

- the session scoped CDI bean which keeps a logged in user,
- the request scoped CDI bean which processes some data and needs (for this purpose) of the instance of currently logged in user.

At the moment when I try to get access to the session scoped bean from request scoped bean (through the `@Inject` annotation) as you see below - I get the `NullPointerException` exception in this line (which is located in `addData` method):

```
String surname=loginController.getCurrentUser().getSurname();
```

Could you tell me how can I fix this issue?

Of course, If I print for example: `#{loginController.currentUser.surname}` from any xhtml pages, everything works but I need access from the bean, not from the xhtml page.

This is a part of login page:

```
<h:form class="form">               

    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="false" />

    <h:inputText id="username" value="#{userLogin.username}" label="Username" required="true" requiredMessage="Username: This field is required." title="Enter your username." pt:placeholder="Username" />                     

    <h:inputSecret  id="password" value="#{userLogin.password}" label="Password" required="true" requiredMessage="Password: This field is required." title="Enter your password." pt:placeholder="Password" />                  

    <p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginController.login}" update="growl" styleClass="buttonStyle"/>                  

</h:form>
```

This is a session scoped CDI bean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class LoginController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6322113716363932422L;

    public String login(){      

        if(userService.login(userLogin)){

            currentUser=userService.getCurrnetUser(userLogin.getUsername());

            return "home?faces-redirect=true";          
        }
        else{

            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Data entered are incorrect"));
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String logout(){

        currentUser=null;

        return "login?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {

          return currentUser!=null;
    }

    @Produces
    @LoggedIn
    public UserAccount getCurrentUser(){

        return currentUser; 
    }   

    @Inject
    private FacesContext facesContext;

    @Inject
    private UserServiceImpl userService;

    @Named
    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    private UserAccount userLogin=new UserAccount();

    private UserAccount currentUser;
}
```

This is a request scoped CDI bean:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class DataServiceImpl implements DataService {

    @Override
    public void addData(String[] data) {

        //Proccess some data

        String surname=loginController.getCurrentUser().getSurname();

        //Proccess some data
    }

    @Inject
    private LoginController loginController;
}
```

This is a stacktrace:

```
18:45:08,968 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-15) #{dataController.send()}: java.lang.NullPointerException: javax.faces.FacesException: #{dataController.send()}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.system.service.DataServiceImpl.addData(DataServiceImpl.java:24)
    at com.system.controller.DataController.send(DataController.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:308)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:415)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:285)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 35 more

18:45:08,971 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-15) javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.system.service.DataServiceImpl.addData(DataServiceImpl.java:24)
    at com.system.controller.DataController.send(DataController.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:308)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:415)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:285)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 35 more
```

This is another CDI bean in which is located a `send` method (from which I call to the `addData` method) which we can see in the stacktrace:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class DataController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1383572529241805730L;

    //some methods

    public void send(){

        if(uploadFile==null){

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "The file isn't uploaded", "You should upload a file"));
        }
        else{

            //Sending the data to the database...

            list=new ArrayList<String>();

            //It should be a upload file but for now I add it manually.
            try(Stream<String> stream=Files.lines(Paths.get("F:/VirtualBox/Share/capture20110815.binetflow"))) {            

                list=stream.collect(Collectors.toList());

                int start=0;                
                Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(",");
                dataService=new DataServiceImpl();

                for (String s : list) {

                    if(start!=0){

                        String[] data=pattern.split(s);

                        dataService.addData(data);
                    }
                    else start++;
                }                           

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }       

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "The data has been added.", ""));           
        }
    }

    @Named
    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    private UserTable userTable=new UserTable();  

    @Inject
    private DataService dataService;

    @Inject
    private FacesContext facesContext;

    @Inject
    private Logger log;

    private UploadedFile uploadFile;
    private List<String> list;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `NullPointerException` is caused by `loginController` object and not by `loginController.getCurrentUser()`?  Post full stacktrace.

Comment: I'm sure because before I checked it by the condidtion `if(loginController==null)` and I received `true`. I edited my post and added the full stacktrace.

Comment: Exception says there is `NullPointerExcpetion` in `#{dataController.send()}`. There is no such thing in your code as `#{dataController.send()}`.

Comment: I use `#{dataController.send()}` in some xhtml page as action for commandButton. I edited my post again and added the DataController bean where is located a `send` method. If you want I can also add the xhtml page where I call `#{dataController.send()}` but I don't think there is a problem there. The page contains one form with a inputText component, a fileUpload component and the commandButton component. From the `send` method I call to the `addData` method which is located in DataServiceImpl bean which code you see above.

Comment: In my opinion the problem is the loginController object in the DataServiceImpl bean because if I don't use this object in bean, I don't receive any exception. Of course maybe I'm wrong and source of the problem is located somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Step by step what I did:

1. I deleted the `LoginController` from the `DataServiceImpl` bean and I injected the `UserAccount` with `@LoggedIn` annotation to the `DataController` bean:

   ```
   @Named
   @ViewScoped
   public class DataController implements Serializable {

       //other fields and methods

       @Inject
       @LoggedIn
       private UserAccount currentUser;
   }
   ```

   You can also inject the `LoginController` to the `DataController` bean instead of the `UserAccount` but it isn't recommended. You would better if you inject the `UserAccount`.
2. I created the `addCurrnetUser()` method in the `DataServiceImpl` class. The parameter of the method is the `UserAccount` object:

   ```
   @Named
   @RequestScoped
   public class DataServiceImpl implements DataService {

       @Override
       public void addCurrentUser(UserAccount currentUser){

           this.currentUser=currentUser;
       }

       @Override
       public void addData(String[] data) {

           //Proccess some data

           String surname=loginController.getCurrentUser().getSurname();

           //Proccess some data
       }

       private UserAccount currentUser;
   }
   ```
3. I called `dataService.addCurrentUser(currentUser)` in `send()` method (which is located in the `DataController` bean) before calling `dataService.addData()`.

You can also have a question: why does the injected `LoginController` returns `null` in the `DataServiceImpl` bean and in the `DataController` bean not? Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228557/inject-annotation-for-object-and-two-different-behaviors-of-this-object) discussion. You can find a few reason there.